# How to test async code with mocha using await

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

How do I test async code with mocha? I wanna use multiple `await` inside mocha

```js
var assert = require('assert');

async function callAsync1() {
  // async stuff
}

async function callAsync2() {
  return true;
}

describe('test', function () {
  it('should resolve', async (done) => {
      await callAsync1();
      let res = await callAsync2();
      assert.equal(res, true);
      done();
      });
});
```

This produces error below:

```
  1) test
       should resolve:
     Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
      at Context.it (test.js:8:4)
```

If I remove done() I get:

```
  1) test
       should resolve:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/tmp/test/test.js)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Mocha [supports Promises out-of-the-box](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises); You just have to `return` the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to `it()`'s callback.

If the Promise resolves then the test passes.
In contrast, if the Promise rejects then the test fails. As simple as that.

Now, since [`async` functions always implicitly return a `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) you can just do:

```
async function getFoo() {
  return 'foo'
}

describe('#getFoo', () => {
  it('resolves with foo', () => {
    return getFoo().then(result => {
      assert.equal(result, 'foo')
    })
  })
})
```

You don't need `done` nor `async` for your `it`.

However, if you still insist on using `async/await`:

```
async function getFoo() {
  return 'foo'
}

describe('#getFoo', () => {
  it('returns foo', async () => {
    const result = await getFoo()
    assert.equal(result, 'foo')
  })
})
```

In either case, **DO NOT** declare `done` as a function argument.

If you use any of the methods described above  you need to remove `done` **completely** from your code. Passing `done` as an argument to `it()` callbacks hints to Mocha that you intent to eventually call it.

Mocha has 3 different ways of ending a test. They aren't meant to be used together.
You pick **one** of the following:

- Return the Promise to `it` and use the `then`/`catch` handlers.
- Use `async/await`
- Use `done`. This is a relic from the old days when we had to deal with callbacks. It still has some use cases, mainly testing callback-style code or events.

Using both Promises *and* `done` will result in:

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both

Technically speaking Promises and `async`/`await` can be used in very similar ways; `async functions` return `Promises` after all and you are always awaiting Promises.
But I digress, just pick a method and go with it all the way.

The `done` method is only used for testing callback-based or event-based code. You shouldn't use it if you're testing Promise-based or async/await functions. If you find yourself having to use both `done` and `Promise.then`/`Promise.catch` semantics, you've probably misunderstood how Promises work and failing tests would be the least of your worries.

Comment: I want to call multiple async code. That's why I put `async` under function. Furthermore I want to make assertion after calling it, so I can't return a promise. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Got it; Edited. Either way when I say you don't need `done`, it means you *shouldn't* even pass it in the `it` callback. Remove `done` completely from your code. Passing `done` as an argument hints to Mocha that you intent to eventually call it.

Comment: I'm doing same as 
async function getFoo() {
  return 'foo'
}

describe('#getFoo', () => {
  it('returns foo', async () => {
    const result = await getFoo()
    assert.equal(result, 'foo')
  })
})

but it gives me this error.
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Do I still not need done()? What is the workaround?

Comment: I don't understand why it fails for async-await, but it worked using promises.

Comment: @Gowthamss and that's the only test in your test file? It looks OK to me. Can you write up a test JS Fiddle I could copy/paste and run?