# Return value on mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

In [some](https://www.serverless.com/blog/tdd-serverless) frameworks, snippet code for mocha tests is auto-generated like this:

```
it('should return current day', () => {
  return wrapped.run({}).then((response) => {
    expect(response.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
    // more tests
  });
});
```

Why is the `return` needed? What is accomplished by returning a value from a mocha test?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641542/2729605

Comment: @malarres I don't completely understand the explanations in that post. So the test expects a resolved promise. Then why not simply use `await` and wait for the resolution yourself? why is the return value needed?

Comment: according to the linked answer, you can do either one or the other. I guess you can choose

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://zaiste.net/posts/modern-nodejs-async-await-testing-mocha-chai/), the return value is obsolete when you use the async/await syntax.