# mocha test passes even though I throw error

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

```
it.only('test', async() => {
    const lol = pdfjs.getDocument({data: data, password: "123"})
    lol.promise.then((ex) => { return ex }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    });
});
```

in this block of code "err" is being printed, and the test passes.
also tried -

```
assert.fail('expected', 'actual', err);
```

and `done()`.

nothing worked, test is still passing every time.

why is this happening?

Comment: You're not _returning_ the promise.

Comment: so how would you do it? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Return it? Await it? All the basic promise operations work just fine with Mocha, it's just JS. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641542/3001761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: await the promise

Just add `await` before the promise expression. You don't even need those `then` and `catch`.

```js
it.only('test', async () => {
    const lol = pdfjs.getDocument({data: data, password: "123"});
    await lol.promise;
});
```

### Option 2: return the promise

If you just return the promise, you don't need to declare the test function as `async`.

```js
it.only('test', () => {
    const lol = pdfjs.getDocument({data: data, password: "123"})
    return lol.promise;
});
```

### Option 3: use a callback

A callback is declared as a parameter of the test function, and is called when the test finished, taking the error as a parameter (if any).

```js
it.only('test', done => {
    const lol = pdfjs.getDocument({data: data, password: "123"})
    lol.promise.then(() => done()).catch((err) => done(err));
});
```

Comment: thanks! I do need the then and catch in order to print the error nicely

Comment: @YardenOrenshtein You can use `then` and `catch` of course, just note that Mocha does also print the error message in the report.

Comment: yes:) I wanted to print only the error.message, because the rest is irrelevant